# Whats the minimum recommended output for a faucet-like system? (April 2017)

Tags: transaction-fees, output, faucets

I am building a software to involve friends. I am testing it. 
I made several sendmany transactions with 43478 Satoshi.
I wont be using high fee Bitcoin system man.......

There are better things coming... like Nimiq... still waiting to see the real thing come out in the following months... sure creating a faucet like system.... or mining for movies... or anything...

I would say $0.05 cents a day? total of $10usd daily among different ip's... this could be hacked...

Answer (score 1):

Faucets in Bitcoin are outdated and economically infeasible today. Fees have been floating between 100 to 300 satoshi/byte. On some weekends they may drop to 20 satoshi/byte for a few hours.

To create a minimal transaction with one input and one output, you already have to purchase `10+148+34=192` byte. Even at only 100 satoshi/byte fee, half of an output with 43,478 satoshi would be consumed in transaction fee. Considering that you already paid for the output to be created, even with batching that's already ~60% of the value lost to fees. Unless you're about to dish out larger amounts, that's going to create more frustration than awe— and who would pay for that?

Comment: Faucets now pay you to an online wallet that only lets you send that money to your wallet when you have reached a certain amount. Other ones pay every one that has reached a certain amount of shatoshi every sunday, to minimize fees.